# TextView size depending on TextView width

Tags: android, textview

Depending on the `TextView` width I want to set the `textSize` as big as possible so that it does NOT exceed the limits.

The problem in my code is that the calcul seems not correct because the text is too big.

I measured the label width (on a screenshot) with Gimp and the variable `textWidthToFit` is correct (in my case 298px)

Here my code (My class overrides `TextView`) :

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    if (stretchable)
    {
        resizeText();
    }

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

private void resizeText()
{
    if (stretchable && (getText().length() > 0))
    {
        float textWidth=0;
        setTextSize(maxTextSize);
        float newTextSize=getPaint().getTextSize();
        int textWidthToFit = getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
        String text = getText().toString();

        boolean sizeFound = false;
        while (!sizeFound)
        {
            newTextSize -= 0.5f;

            paint.setTextSize(newTextSize);
            textWidth = paint.measureText(text);

            if (textWidth < textWidthToFit || newTextSize < 5)
            {
                sizeFound = true;
            }

        }

        setTextSize(newTextSize);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Comment: Note that there are already libraries that offer this, like https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview.

Comment: Thank you, it seem to be ok !

Comment: @CommonsWare Right the one I wanted to suggest: implemented today - works great!